# Pyvmomi How to disable/enable vsan silent checks

Tags: python-3.x, pyvmomi

I've been reading the documentation for pyvmomi but it's not clear on how to use the function
`VsanHealthSetVsanClusterSilentChecks` from the managed object `vim.cluster.VsanVcClusterHealthSystem`, it doesn't say how to initialize or how to instance the object or show any example on how to use it.

i have tried code like this:

```
vchs = vim.cluster.VsanVcClusterHealthSystem('vsan-cluster-health-system')
check = vchs.VsanHealthSetVsanClusterSilentChecks(cluster, None, alarm_list)
```

The code throws an exception but it's not very descriptive:

```
VsanVcClusterHealthSystem
```

and that is all from the exception error message.

[Pyvmomi documentation for VsanHealthSetVsanClusterSilentChecks](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/ab9fe266-2b43-46a4-942f-421f5476811c/b1251755-f799-497b-8541-d0186766b8f4/vim.cluster.VsanVcClusterHealthSystem.html#setVsanClusterSilentChecks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that pyvmomi on it's own can't do that, i needed to use `vSAN Management SDK for Python`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to retrieve `VsanVcClusterHealthSystem` object from the `content` property of the service instance!

something like this :

```
from pyVim import connect

#don't forget to replace vcenter_server, username and password with yours
si = connect.SmartConnectNoSSL(host="vcenter_server", user="username", pwd="password")

#get the content property of the service instance
content = si.RetrieveContent()

#get the vSphere API root folder
root_folder = content.rootFolder

#get the cluster object by name and ensure that the cluster object is correctly obtained from the root folder
cluster = root_folder.childEntity[0]

#get the VsanVcClusterHealthSystem object from the cluster
vchs = cluster['vsan-cluster-health-system']

#calling the VsanHealthSetVsanClusterSilentChecks function
check = vchs.VsanHealthSetVsanClusterSilentChecks(cluster, None, alarm_list)
```